# Is it possible to code an ASP.NET/MVC project that can talk to SharePoint Online/Office 365 API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, office365apis

Bottom line: I dont want to code on SharePoint 2016 or online, ive done it before, its a pain and clunky experience and other issues.

I am a developer and i code mostly in C# using ASP.NET/MVC and started coding using Core. I have a project to build but i want to use SharePoint online as the "storage" but I want to build a completely separate frontpage and set of UIs on an MVC project.

For example, if i were to make a small app that records production numbers, users would go to my MVC app and enter the new number. This data then gets inserted to some list on SharePoint Online/365 which we created using the out-of-the-box tool. Similarly on the MVC web app the user can run a report that runs a query on the SharePoint Online list and returns the data which is then graphed out using visualization libraries on the MVC app.

I would like to know if it is possible to design the lists etc to hold the content on SharePoint Online and make the MVC website talk to those lists (CRUD operations) and display the content back into the MVC project? And would there be an API i should be looking into?

We have an O365 license for SharePoint Online, O365 etc and we would be hosting the MVC application on Azure included in our package with Microsoft.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SharePoint REST API. Any technology that can make web services calls can interact with SharePoint content. (Actually, perform just about any SharePoint activity.)

So, MVC C# would work, as would JavaScript, PowerShell and just about everything else. Your biggest challenge will be working out how you want to deal with user authentication. (Who can do what.) The REST services honor permissions.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

I have a GitHub project with sample JavaScript and HTML that lets you experiment with the SharePoint REST API. https://github.com/microsmith/SharePointRESTtester

On-prem SharePoint also has a server side API. But, REST works well there too.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you i completely forgot about SharePoint REST. I will try out your GitHub project, thanks again. And yes about the authentication I thought of managing it the old fashion way by AD-groups. Not too bad since we dont have many users for this project.